# Can a debian package have a dependency on a snap package?

Tags: deb, snap

We have an application that is packaged as a debian (.deb) package.
The application is deployed on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

We are looking to provide the application on 16.04 when it is released.  However, one of the applications's dependencies -- couchdb -- is available as a snap package and not as a debian package.

Is there a way to tell the debian package that it requires a particular snap to be installed?

Comment: Hmmm. Ubuntu 16.04 was released --on time-- two years ago. And the `couchdb` deb package is indeed in both 14.04 and 16.04 (and every release since). Ubuntu 18.04 will be released later this month...and also has a `couchdb` deb.

Answer (score 3):

No, these are independent packaging systems.  You can use `debian/control` to specify another debian package using the `Depends: xxx` syntax but not a snap.  This is the whole point about snaps: they bundle their own dependencies to prevent things like distro version mismatches, etc.

Maybe you want to consider packaging your application as a snap?

Comment: how about the opposite? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113031/can-a-snap-package-depend-on-a-deb-package-provided-by-the-distro

Comment: You can however run `snap install XYZ` in the `postinst` script and then maybe do `snap remove XYZ` at the `prerm` script.